# Load directive based on translation string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-translate

So I want to insert a directive into the html page based on the translation that comes from angular-translate. 
Lets say I have these two directives:

```
.directive('englishText', function() {
  return {
    template: 'Hello'
  };
});
.directive('spanishText', function() {
  return {
    template: 'Hola'
  };
});
```

And I have these two json files from which will the translation come:

```
english.json
{
"LANGUAGE" : "english-text"
}
```

---

```
spanish.json
{
"LANGUAGE" : "spanish-text"
}
```

So on the html page I want to have something like that:

```
<div {{'LANGUAGE' | translate}}></div>
```

But as an output I jsut get this:

```
<div {{'language' | translate}}></div>
```

instead of

```
<div english-text>Hello</div>
```

I also tried this:

```
<{{'LANGUAGE' | translate></{{'LANGUAGE' | translate}}>
```

But I get this as an output

```
<english-text>
```

Which is interpreted just like an innerHTML and not like a tag...

Comment: Why would you want this, this seems like super bad practise. That aside, you can't do that in your template, you need to do that in a parent directive which `$compile()`s the subdirective

Comment: You should have 1 directive which can handle all translations, not a different directive for each translation. How is the English directive different from the Spanish one, other than the language of course?

Comment: @Rhumborl it's no different than just the template... I just simplified the question so only the main point should be there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on doing it the way you've asked this is the way to do it, the parent directive will `$compile` a language based directive and replace the inner html to the new directive

```
.directive('languageDirective', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: linkFn,
        scope: {
            language: '@'
        }
    };

    function linkFn(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.html(
            $compile(getTemplate)($scope)
        );
    }

    function getTemplate() {
        if(scope.language === 'english')
            return '<div english-directive></div>'
        else
            return '<div other-directive></div>'
    }
});
```

Comment: I can't understand how to actually use this, can you give me some source of information from which I could learn more about your solution or if you can explain it in more detail?

Comment: In your template you can do something like `<div language-directive language="'english'"></div>`, this will then load the english directive and place it in it's contents. More info about `$compile` here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: Hmm, I had to put $compile and $scope into the directive but even after that there is an error `Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20languageDirectiveDirective`

Comment: @VasilEmilov Sorry, there were some errors in my code, I've updated my answer

Comment: @Martin Welker, the error is still there. Maybe there is something wrong with the directives I have. They look like that
         `.directive('englishDirective', function() {
   return {
    template: 'Hello'
   };
 })
.directive('spanish-directive', function() {
   return {
    template: 'Hola'
   };
 })`

Comment: Could you put it in a plunkr ?

Comment: @VasilEmilov http://plnkr.co/edit/KALGpXjFjK9b2oVJuQci?p=preview sorry, here it is

Comment: so we are now at the point where I need this language attribute to be changed via button click which changes the translation of the page, and according to that, to load the appropriate directive... I need this to happen on button click, not just on pageload

Comment: @VasilEmilov Updated the plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/KALGpXjFjK9b2oVJuQci?p=preview

Comment: So, this is my last question. Why does the button created from the directive doesn't work? Here is the plnkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/qV0KAuvQxrxKgwm3S5o6?p=preview

Comment: @VasilEmilov Because the directive has an `isolated scope`, here's an updated plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/5XouwWOLee8mA7LImvwe?p=preview. More info about scopes here http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-2-isolate-scope

Comment: Thank you master :) Thank you for taking your time to explain this to me :)